# Receive many UDP packets & ksoftirqd load

Tags: networking

I want my server to be able to handle more than 1Mpps from a 10g card. 
Is it possible? I have Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.11 and a 16 core Xeon machine.
It seems that ksoftirqd becomes bottleneck in 300kpps.

Is there any guide on how to tune the server handle this load?

Comment: A whole lot can be done. Please specify hardware, card make/model, and nature of the workload. What type of data are you consuming?

Comment: The card is Intel E10G42BT X520-T2 10Gigabit Ethernet Card. The workload I'm testing right now is 64B UDP packets generated by netperf. CPU is  E5-2650 v2 @ 2.60GHz, 16 cores with hyperthreading.

Comment: I thought ksoftirq tries to handle interrupts. When I look at /proc/interrupts, the numbers do not increase a lot (10 per core per second) but ksoftireq uses 100% of a core when the server tries to receive 600kpps.

Does ksoftirq also handles DMA received packets? I have enabled IOAT DMA. 
Does ksoftirq is called per network packets? I have set interruptthrottling as 16000,16000 for my 10G NIC (ixgbe driver).

Comment: iptables processing runs almost all of the network stack in softirq context. Do you have a lot of rules or modules with a heavy workload like conntrack loaded?

Comment: No I didn't add any rule into iptables or install any additional modules besides whatever original ubuntu installs. It is just a fresh install to test how many packets the server can process per second.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is a kernel-bypass engine (that's the easiest option for my opinion). There are currently 2 popular engines that do that and can reach packet sending in line-rate:

- [DPDK](http://dpdk.org/) - it supports [your card](http://dpdk.org/doc/nics) (Intel 82599) and should work on your OS
- [PF_RING ZC](http://www.ntop.org/products/packet-capture/pf_ring/pf_ring-zc-zero-copy/) - also supports your card and should work on you OS

I've used both of them and after some learning curve time I must say they're really convenient and easy to use

Comment: Yes, I use them other other projects, but I want to push the Linux kernel to the limit. It seems there are lots of configuration and hidden techniques to improve the bound

Answer (score 0):

Here's a handy article, even though this was asked 9 months ago:

https://blog.cloudflare.com/how-to-receive-a-million-packets/

Basically the answer is yes, pretty easily.  Right now I've got a UDP server receiving 1.08Mpps, on a 20@2.6Ghz core Xeon machine with Intel 82599 10G NIC.

My configuration is basically:
  Ubuntu 14.04 with 3.13.0-57-lowlatency (LL makes a difference)
  isolcpus kernel flag excluding cores 10-19 (one NUMA node)
  UDP server process taskset to core 10
  RX queue hardware interrupts serviced by core 11
  RPS for RX queue mapped to core 12

CPU usage is 100% on core 10, ~45% hardware interrupt servicing on core 11, and 100% ksoftirqd on core 12.  All other cores usage is negligible.

I've experimented with using 100% of all 20 cores and achieved around 7Mpps, but I'm sure it could be optimized even more.

Of course, you could just use DPDK and stop messing with all those interrupts.